# How to split text value into array with words in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Is it possible to save value of `txtSearche` in array splitted into seperate words?

```
txtSearche = "put returns between paragraphs";
```

something like this:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txtSearche);

array1 = sb[1]   = put
array2 = sb[2]   = returns
array3 = sb[3]
array4 = sb[4]
array5 = sb[5]
```

how to do it correct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes try this:

```
string[] words = txtSearche.Split(' ');
```

which will give you:

```
words[0]   = put
words[1]   = returns
words[2]   = between
words[3]   = paragraphs
```

**EDIT:** Also as **Adkins** mentions below, the words array will be created to whatever size is needed by the string that is provided. If you want the list to have a dynamic size I would say drop the array into a list using List wordList = words.ToList();

**EDIT: Nakul** to split by one space or more, just add them as parameters into the `Split()` method like below:

```
txtSearche.Split(new string[] { " ", "  ", "   " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

or you can tell it simply to split by a single space and ignore entries that are blank, caused by consecutive spaces, by using the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` enum like so

```
txtSearche.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the words array will be created to whatever size is needed by the string that is provided.  If you want the list to have a dynamic size I would say drop the array into a list using List<string> wordList = words.ToList<string>();

Comment: @Adkins: Thanks I'll add it to the answer

Comment: I want to know what return when consecutive spaces in string

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Comment: And, yes, there's also a `Join`.

Answer (score 2):

Below example will split the string into an array with each word as an item...

string[] words = txtSearche.Split(' ');

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

None of above work with **multiple spaces or new line**!!!

Here is what works with them:

```
 string text = "hi!\r\nI am     a wonderful56 text... \r\nyeah...";
 string[] words =Regex.Split(text, @"\s+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

If you need to remove ellipsis then more processing is required and i can give you that as well.

**UPDATE**

In fact this is better:

```
 string text = "hi!\r\nI am     a wonderful56 text... \r\nyeah...";
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"[\w\d_]+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
   if(match.Success)
      Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
  }
```

**Outputs**:

hi
I
am
a
wonderful56
text
yeah

Comment: That's not entirely true, `String.Split` has an overload that takes an array of split characters, and an option to skip empty entries, so you could use `text.Split(" \t\r\n\x85\xA0.,;:!?()-\"".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.  If you're going to go all the way to regex though, `@"\W+(?<!')"` would be better than `@"\s+"`, since it would remove punctuation as well (the `(?<!')` is to protect contractions and possessives, with the unfortunate side effect that it won't remove single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(txtSearche); 

var result  =  sb.Tostring().Split(' ');
```

Comment: `new StringBuilder(txt).ToString()` = no-op

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more complete solution and don't exactly worry about performance, you can have this one-liner take care of punctuation, etc. and give you an array of only the words.

```
string[] words = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", " "), @"\s+", " ").Split(' ');
```

Comment: This adds an empty string entry to the beginning or end of the array (or both) if the source text has whitespaces at the beginning or end. So it needs Trim() before using.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = textBox1.Text;            
    string[] words = s.Split(' ');           
    textBox2.Text = words[0];
    textBox3.Text = words[1];
}
```